# “Qu’est-ce que tu fais ?” vs. “Tu fais quoi ?”

Tags: sens, expressions, questions

Je viens de lire [un article en ligne](http://blog.francedc.org/five-ways-to-sound-more-french/), mais je ne comprends pas du tout. Il dit :

> Example: Rather than saying, *Qu’est-ce que tu fais ?* [What are you doing?], you can simply say, *Tu fais quoi ?*
>
> Or, instead of *Pourquoi a-t-il dit ça ?* [Why did he say that?], just ask, *Pourquoi t’as dit ça ?* For emphasis, you might even add, *Pourquoi t’as dit ça, toi ?*

Pourquoi le sujet de « il » dans « Pourquoi a-t-il dit ça ? » devient « tu » dans le cas de la conversation courante ?

Comment: Tu n'as pas fait de lien vers la page en ligne où tu as lu ça mais je pense que c'est [celle-ci](http://blog.francedc.org/five-ways-to-sound-more-french/). C'est une faute de frappe, bien entendu ce devrait être écrit : **Pourquoi as-tu dit ça ? [Whey did you say that]**. Ton titre ne correspond à la question que tu poses, j'espère que j'ai bien compris ce que tu demandais.  Bien entendu *il* ne peut pas remplacer *tu*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, Laure, vous êtes tout à fait raison! Je vois.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je confirme le commentaire ci-dessus. C'est une erreur de rédaction.

Pour la phrase : « Pourquoi a-t-il dit ça ? », l'autre possibilité est : « Pourquoi il a dit ça ? » Alors que pour la phrase : « Pourquoi as-tu dit ça ? », c'est : « Pourquoi t'as dit ça ? »

Tu peux tout à fait contacter le rédacteur de ce texte et l'en informer.